# Combining a nested list without affecting the key and value direction in python

Tags: python, list

I have a program that stores data in a list. The **current** and **desired** output is in the format:

```py
# Current Input
[{'Devices': ['laptops', 'tablets'],
  'ParentCategory': ['computers', 'computers']},

 {'Devices': ['touch'], 'ParentCategory': ['phones']}]

# Desired Output
[{'Devices': ['laptops', 'tablets','touch'],
  'ParentCategory': ['computers', 'computers','phones']}]
```

Can you give me an idea on how to combine the lists with another python line of code or logic to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def convert(a):
    d = {}
    for x in a:
        for key,val in x.items():
            if key not in d:
                d[key] = []
            d[key] += val
    return d
```

Code above is for Python 3.

If you're on Python 2.7, then I believe that you should replace `items` with `iteritems`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using a dict comprehension: build the merged dictionary first by figuring out which keys it should have, then by concatenating all the lists for each key. The set of keys, and each resulting list, are built using [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```py
from itertools import chain

def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    return {
        k: list(chain.from_iterable( d[k] for d in dicts if k in d ))
        for k in set(chain.from_iterable(dicts))
    }
```

Usage:

```py
>>> merge_dicts({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5]}, {'a': [6, 7], 'c': [8]})
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 6, 7], 'b': [4, 5], 'c': [8]}
>>> ds = [
    {'Devices': ['laptops', 'tablets'],
     'ParentCategory': ['computers', 'computers']},
    {'Devices': ['touch'],
     'ParentCategory': ['phones']}
]
>>> merge_dicts(*ds)
{'ParentCategory': ['computers', 'computers', 'phones'],
 'Devices': ['laptops', 'tablets', 'touch']}
```