# How can i combine a list of dicts to a list of dicts combining like keys

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I want to take this input:

```
mycounter = [{6: ['Credit card']}, {2: ['Debit card']}, {2: ['Check']}]                                                                                                                                                        
#[{6: ['Credit card']}, {2: ['Debit card']}, {2: ['Check']}]
```

And achieve this Desired Output:

```
[{6: ['Credit card']}, {2: ['Debit card', 'Check']}]
```

My attempt was the following, but it's not matching desired output. Any help here is appreciated. Thx.

```
temp = list(zip([*map(lambda d: next(iter(d.keys())), mycounter)], [*map(lambda d: next(iter(d.values())), mycounter)]))  

c = collections.defaultdict(list)
for a,b in temp:
   c[a].extend(b)

final = [dict(c)]
# Close, but not quite the desired output since it's should be two dict objects, not one
# [{6: ['Credit card'], 2: ['Debit card', 'Check']}]
```

My searches on stackoverflow found solutions that combine with giving None values, but nothing like what i'm asking for. My question has a different input than another similar question earlier.

Comment: Are you sure you want the output to have individual dictionaries, rather than all of the keys together in one dictionary? I can't imagine why you'd want a list of dictionaries with one key each.

Comment: I don't need them that way, i just wanted to know the best way to accomplish the task.  I was having trouble figuring out how to answer another question and was stuck here and i wanted to know how to fix what stumped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to make a single dictionary then break it into single key-value pairs after:

```
mycounter = [{6: ['Credit card']}, {2: ['Debit card']}, {2: ['Check']}]                                                                                                                                                        

res = {}
for d in mycounter:
    for k, v in d.items():
        res.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
[{k:v} for k, v in res.items()]
# [{6: ['Credit card']}, {2: ['Debit card', 'Check']}]
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of giving options, here is an alternate version that uses defaultdict, which I find easier to use especially as complexity increases:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for d in mycounter:
    for k, v in d.items():
        result[k] += v

In : result
Out: defaultdict(list, {6: ['Credit card'], 2: ['Debit card', 'Check']})
```

Defaultdict behaves like dict for the most part but if necessary it can be converted to one with:

```
In : dict(result)
Out: {6: ['Credit card'], 2: ['Debit card', 'Check']}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844629/combining-a-nested-list-without-affecting-the-key-and-value-direction-in-python); the only difference is that you want each key/value pair in its own dictionary. Here's an adapted solution using comprehensions and itertools:

```py
from itertools import chain

def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    return [
        { k: list(chain.from_iterable( d[k] for d in dicts if k in d )) }
        for k in set(chain.from_iterable(dicts))
    ]
```

Comment: Thx kaya3, i like these itertools solutions, i didn't think about chain